How do write to register 0 in MIPI RFFE chips?
I am trying to use the following SP6T Switch. Specifically, I want to write to the register 0 so that I can control the channels used as in the image below -

Now, according to the MIPI standards, a register 0 write is as follows -

From the datasheet, I thought that the slave address of the device is 0b1001 (0x09).

The parity bit is odd (also referenced from the datasheet). So I gave the following to the SDATA (yellow) and SCLK(blue) using bit banging, hoping that the SDATA would be transmitted at the negative edges of the clock.

I still did not see anything at the output of the switch. Then I read something on the datasheet along the lines of -
The RFFE SDATA signal is bidirectional, driven by the Master or a Slave. Data shall be written on the rising
edge (transition from logical level zero to logical level one) of the SCLK signal by both Master and Slaves.
Each node on the bus, Master or Slave, shall read the data on the falling edge (transition from logical level
one to logical level zero) of the SCLK signal.
So I tried using the rising edge of the clock to shift the data.

But I still do not see any output. Please let me know if what I am doing is correct and if not, what am I doing wrong. Thanks

dont have experience with RFFE, but google suggests SCLK streching is not necessarily supported by the slave, and you should keep the SCLK active if you hope to receive an answer, as it is similar to I2C

@markus-nm - where did you see that? The links that I saw (https://x.com/olegkutkov/status/1483586595810947078/photo/2) say SLCK goes low after bus park cycle.
